# Why am I not getting the desired output for this program using pointers in functions in c?

Tags: c, function, pointers, error-handling, pass-by-pointer

**Header file**:  circlehead.h

```
#include <stdio.h>
void circle_Data(float *r);
#define PI 3.14f
```

**C FILE1:**  circle.c

```
#include "circlehead.h"
void circle_Data(float *r)
{
    float ar=0,peri=0;
    ar= PI * (*r) * (*r);
    peri=2 * PI * (*r);
}
```

**MAIN FUNCTION** circle_main.c

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include "circlehead.h"
int main()
{
    float r=5.24;
float  ar, peri;
    
    circle_Data(&r);
    printf("Area is %f", ar);
    printf("Perimeter is %f", peri);
}
```

I have linked the files into a single executable:

```
gcc -c circle.c
gcc -c circle_main.c
gcc -o x_exe circle.o circle_main.o 
./x_exe
```

But I am getting the output as area: 3.728 and perimeter: 0.000
The code was compiled successfully. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You do know that the variable `ar` and `peri` in the `main` function are totally separate and distinct from the variables with the same name in the `circle_Data` function?

Comment: There's also no need to pass `r` using a pointer.

Comment: (1) `circle_Data` doesn't do anything, and if optimizing, it will probably be optimized away.  All it does is compute some values, storing them in local variables that are discarded when it returns (2) It doesn't make sense to pass pointers instead of values unless you actually need pointers for some reason (3) Don't use `3.14f` for PI.  By today's standards, it's very inaccurate.  Use `M_PI` instead, defined in `math.h`. (4) Unless there's a genuine reason to use `float`, you should use `double` instead (again, more accurate).

Comment: Add `-Wall` to your compile commands to get better warnings. I got warnings about `ar` and `peri` being used without being initialized when I compiled your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You had the right idea (passing a pointer) but you used it in the wrong way.

The problem was that you passed a pointer to the variable that *wouldn't* be changed, and didn't pass pointers to the variables that you *did* need to be changed, by `circle_Data()`. This version ought to behave in the way you wanted. The values of `ar` and `peri` that are local to `main()` are modified by `circle_Data()`, and the correct values can then be printed.

Note that `circle_Data()` gets a *copy* of `r` that it can modify, but that won't change the value of `r` in `main()`. It's a totally separate variable, just as `ar` and `peri` were in your first version.

```
#include "circlehead.h"
void circle_Data(float r, float* ar, float* peri )
{
    *ar= PI * r * r;
    *peri=2 * PI * r;
}


#include<stdio.h>
#include "circlehead.h"
int main()
{
    float r=5.24;
    float ar, peri;
    
    circle_Data(r, &ar, &peri);
    printf("Area is %f", ar);
    printf("Perimeter is %f", peri);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You never assign `ar` or `peri` any values in `main`, so those variables don't every get assigned any values. That different variables with the same names get assigned elsewhere doesn't matter. (And the language would be pretty much unusable if it did.)

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like the below. The problem is caused by the fact that you never pass in ar or peri by reference. So you code does not change them.

Main

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include "circlehead.h"


int main()
{
  float r = 5.24;
  float ar = 0;
  float peri = 0;
    
    circle_Data(r, ar, peri);
    printf("Area is %f", ar);
    printf("Perimeter is %f", peri);

    return 0;
}
```

Header

```
#include <stdio.h>
void circle_Data(float r, float &ar, float &peri);
#define PI 3.14f
```

Body

```
#include "circlehead.h"
void circle_Data(float r, float &ar, float &peri)
{
    ar = PI * (r) * (r);
    peri = 2 * PI * (r);
}
```